# Count at specific cell

Tags: vba, excel

I know this is going to be an easy tweak, however I have tried a number of variations and have also been on Google and this forum with little luck.

The code I have so far gives me a row count for column B, with a return value of 225. However I want the count to begin at cell "B17" to return a value of 209. This is because B17 is the beginning of a table within my spreadsheet that will hold a variable amount of data.

The code so far is:

```
With ActiveSheet
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").END(xlUp).row
End With
```

Thanks in advance

[[image: Results when using the code]

[image: Ultimate Result]

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim startRow As Double
Dim lastRow As Double
Dim procCol As Double
Dim i As Double

'I will preface this with you should not use activesheet
'you should declare:
'Dim thisWS As Worksheet
'Set thisWS = Thisworkbook.Worksheets("yourworksheetname")
'and use thisWS where you see Activesheet

startRow = ActiveSheet.Range("K16").row
procCol = ActiveSheet.Range("K16").Column

lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, procCol).END(xlUp).row

'for RGB use a tool like
'https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_picker.asp


  For i = startRow To lastRow 'this will run through the rows, it's dynamic
   If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, procCol).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, procCol) Then

            Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2), ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 20)).Interior.Color = RGB(220, 230, 241) 'this is light blue
            Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 2), ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 20)).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255) 'this is light blue

   Else 'Do nothing

   End If
Next i

End Sub
```

The only thing I have changed is the reference cell from B to K, extended the range so that it fills a row not a cell and updated the colour?

Comment: What's wrong with -16? If B17 is fixed anyway, you might as well go for the faster solution rather than specifying a constant cell and asking for it's row number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**"Thanks this actually seems to work. Ultimately I'm trying to find the last row in my table (as it varies). The next stage to work out is to try and format the data so that I can put a different fill colour every time a certain value matches the row below. The idea being that the data is more readable by seeing the rows separated by colour. The issue is sometime 2 rows might match, sometimes 10 etc. – Carlos80 8 hours ago"**

This code will do what you want, if you want a different color for each selection the code will have to be modified slightly.  It will dynamically range the column you hard code, you can also change the column or the starting row of the column easily.  Check it out, it is simple but will do what you want based on B17 to the end of the column with data.

**Updated to interleave your colors if new matches are right on top of one another ****

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()


Dim startRow As Double
Dim lastRow As Double
Dim procCol As Double
Dim i As Double

'I will preface this with you should not use activesheet
'you should declare:
'Dim thisWS As Worksheet
'Set thisWS = Thisworkbook.Worksheets("yourworksheetname")
'and use thisWS where you see Activesheet

startRow = ActiveSheet.Range("B17").Row
procCol = ActiveSheet.Range("B17").Column

lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, procCol).End(xlUp).Row

'for RGB use a tool like
'https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_picker.asp


  For i = startRow To lastRow 'this will run through the rows, it's dynamic
   If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, procCol).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, procCol)  Then

            ActiveSheet.Cells(i, procCol).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 204, 255) 'this is light blue
            ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, procCol).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 204, 255) 'this is light blue

   Else 'Do nothing

   End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Cheers, Wookie

Comment: Wookie, this is amazing thanks so much for your help! This gives me almost all of what I need apart from I'm looking to color fill a row with the column range B:T and also it doesn't seem to color fill all of the matching rows the last matching value is a different color. Not sure if there is a way to show you this separately from this thread.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the data that is not being colored properly or matched?  I updated the answer to show that is not happening for me at all.  Perhaps that multiple matches are back to back, there is not a check for this in the code, but it would be to not color if the previous row does not match and was previously colored.

Comment: If you do not want two consecutive matches to be the same color, we will have to interleave the color choices in that case, the code will have to be modified.

Comment: Hi Wookie, had to explain by typing so I have uploaded some images.

Comment: strange, can you post the code that presents that behavior?  The striping is a little trickier to pull off.

Comment: Hi Wookie, I have updated the question with the code I'm using. Not much has really been changed

Comment: And Latitude is in column K?  If so I am wondering how many digits are carried in the cell and how many are shown . . . . . . equal is equal, until they are not, haha.  The code I gave you would have made that whole section blue with no striping.  They are all matches, if you want striping, then we will modify accordingly, but first solve the not equal issue and I would be looking at significant digits.

Answer (score 2):

if you need to count rows between 17 (included) and current cell, it is really simple:

```
LastRow = Range(ActiveSheet.Range("A17"), Range("A" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Rows.Count
```

Comment: this is a misnomer to call this last row, call it numRows just in case.  It is no the last row of data it is the number of rows with data for what you specify.  if you are starting at cell 17 and have data to row 34 you son't want to be thinking lastRow is 18.

Comment: well, I don't know what Carlos is using this variable for, that is why I didn't changed it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried like this:

```
With ActiveSheet
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row - .Range("B17").Row
End With
```

It really depends what you want actually. But in the case above you would simply remove `17` from the result. Consider adding `+1` to `LastRow` to get what you actually want.

Like this `LastRow = LastRow +1`

Comment: Thanks this actually seems to work. Ultimately I'm trying to find the last row in my table (as it varies). The next stage to work out is to try and format the data so that I can put a different fill colour every time a certain value matches the row below. The idea being that the data is more readable by seeing the rows separated by colour. The issue is sometime 2 rows might match, sometimes 10 etc.

Comment: @ put a different fill colour every time a certain value matches the row below. - this may be done with conditional formatting

Comment: @Marcin - Correct

Comment: I would be careful.  You know your start and last row will give you the end.  What you are calculating is the number of rows.  use the code above but do not call it last row, call it number of rows.  NumRows = Last Row - startRow (17) + 1 (the plus on is the inclusion of the starting row).  Using a for loop you don't need this you can just use start and last as boundaries.  Ex. row 10 - row 1 = 9, but if you are running code row 1 to row 10 you add 1 for number of rows.

Comment: Again this usually is not necessary when you know the start and stop and use FOR loops.  If you want to break the loop early in the range based on condition there are many ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If your table is Excel Data Table (Insert > Table) you can try to count rows like this:

```
Set tbl = Sheets("Your_Sheet").ListObjects("Your_table")
rows_no = tbl.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
Debug.Print rows_no
```